Azure pipeline not installing dependency
I've added 'cypress-wait-until' to my project. The tests all run locally both from the dashboard and headless mode. But when they're triggered from the pipeline in azure they all fail because they can't resolve the new package. Do I need to have a pipeline task that installs the cypress-wait-until package before it builds the tests to run them?
2024-10-31T15:36:00.4638003Z   Running:  add-essential-item-to-basket.cy.ts                                              (1 of 9)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8123501Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8128234Z Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8128603Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8129030Z   > cypress/support/e2e.js
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8130773Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8131891Z The error was:
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8132124Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8132500Z Error: Webpack Compilation Error
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8133621Z Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-wait-until' in '/azp/_work/1/s/cypress/support'
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8134898Z     at handle (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:212:23)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8135730Z     at finalCallback (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:441:32)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8136173Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:505:17
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8136559Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8137316Z     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8137818Z     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8138237Z     at Cache.storeBuildDependencies (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:122:37)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8138641Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:501:19
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8139086Z     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8140210Z     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8140875Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:498:23
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8141286Z     at Compiler.emitRecords (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:919:5)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8141662Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:490:11
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8142032Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:885:14
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8142479Z     at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8142963Z     at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8143369Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:882:27
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8143947Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8144438Z     at done (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8144832Z     at alreadyWritten (/root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:714:8)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8145223Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:802:19
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8145735Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8146312Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8146915Z     at /root/.cache/Cypress/13.13.1/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8147320Z     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8147523Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8148145Z This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8148369Z 
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8148805Z - A missing file or dependency
2024-10-31T15:36:07.8149291Z - A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

This works when I'm running my tests locally:
$ yarn cy:test
yarn run v1.22.21
$ yarn run cleanE2EReports && yarn run cy:terminal && yarn merge-reports && yarn create-html-report
$ rm -fr cypress/reports
$ cypress run --browser chrome


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52722/devtools/browser/755f7ae8-10e3-4ea8-9fe3-f7ecb8c63b50

====================================================================================================

  (Run Starting)

  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:        13.13.1                                                                        │
  │ Browser:        Chrome 129 (headless)                                                          │
  │ Node Version:   v20.9.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)                                     │
  │ Specs:          9 found (add-essential-item-to-basket.cy.ts, add-product-to-basket-using-quick │
  │                 view.cy.ts, add-product-to-wishlist.cy.ts, checkout-stripe-failed.cy.ts, check │
  │                 out-stripe-success.cy.ts, complete-checkout-retrieves-order.cy.ts, complete-ch │
  │                 eckout-with-promo-code...)                                                     │
  │ Searched:       cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.ts                                                         │
  │ Experiments:    experimentalRunAllSpecs=true,experimentalMemoryManagement=true,experimentalWe… │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

  Running:  add-essential-item-to-basket.cy.ts                                              (1 of 9)


  Add product with and without essential item using the essential items modal
    √ Add product to basket and a essential item using the essentials items modal with StandardNoCheckout & TEST1V2EG (8461ms)
    √ Add product to basket with no essentials items with StandardNoCheckout & TEST1V0EG (8995ms)


  2 passing (18s)

[mochawesome] Report JSON saved to C:\Users\paul.heathcote\Repos\WebsiteWebApp\cypress\reports\mocha\mochawesome.json

[mochawesome] Report HTML saved to C:\Users\paul.heathcote\Repos\WebsiteWebApp\cypress\reports\mocha\mochawesome.html

